# AppDelegate, LoginHome, TabBar, and HTTP GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

In my application I currently have a Navigation Controller as the initial view controller. This very NavigationController links my app in the following manner, where NC=NavigationController,VC=ViewController,TC=TabBarController:

```
NC->LoginHomeVC->TC->(rest of app)
```

I have read that TabBarViewController's must be a root view controller(I assume this does not imply that it must be "initial VC")
**In my AppDelegate.m**'s didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com/xxx/xxx"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if([result isEqualToString: @"logged"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarControl"];
        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
        NSLog(@"It's hitting log");
    }

    else if([result isEqualToString: @"notlogged"])
    {
        //do nothing
        NSLog(@"It's hitting notlog.");

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JumpToLogin"];
        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);

    return YES;
}
```

So my conditions simply check whether or not the user is logged in and takes them to the `TabBarViewController` if they are, and to the `LoginHomeViewController` if they aren't. Currently my code for "*logged*" instigates a push to the `TabBarController`. Also my *login button* on my `LoginHomeVC` modal segues to the `TabBarController`. when the push executes, my `NavController` on my `TabController`'s initial view loses color and buttons and all, all of which are set in my TC's initial VC's class.

*QUESTION:*  Do I need to separate the `LoginHomeVC` from the `TabBarVC` and set the `TabBarVC` as the initial VC, or can I just programmatically modal segue to the `TabBarVC`(push is probably why I'm losing buttons,etc), or am I approaching this `LoginHome->TabBar` completely wrong?

**EDIT:** What is the **easiest** approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Your **TabBarControl** as rootview and just present model your loginview controller if user not login.

Comment: Do you mean, check off "Is initial view controller" for *rootview*? @Viruss mca

Comment: That requires to switch all connections that are established thus far.  Cannot I not just conditionally perform a modal segue from the app's beginning `NavController` to the `TabBarController`

Comment: The only problem with your answer is that I currently have a segue from the login button on my `loginHome` going to the tabBarController, would it be alright to have that segue going back to the initial view controller? @Viruss mca

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince:is it giving any problem?